# If / else statements in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, syntax

[image]

Why does this work?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The box is not checked!");
        }
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            if (label1.BackColor == Color.Red)
            {
                label1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
            else
            {
                label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't?

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The box is not checked!");
        }
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            if (label1.BackColor == Color.Red)
            {
                label1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
            if (label1.BackColor == Color.Blue)
            {
                label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

I would think that the compliler would read the lines each time I press the button so it should not be any different to have two if statements after each other.

Comment: Short answer: in the 2nd approach the 2 if/then statements are not independent. The 1st influences the 2nd.

Comment: This isn't actually specific to C#, this type of code would produce the same problem in every programming language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are changing to blue if it was red **and then** your are changing it to red if it was blue. Basically first if first `if` will change it to blue then second `if` will change it back to red. It works this way because instructions are executed sequentially, so your second `if` is always checked after your first `if`. Just use `else if` so second `if` won't work if first one fired:

```
// if red then change to blue
if (label1.BackColor == Color.Red)
{
    label1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
// otherwise, if blue then change to red
// this condition will be checked if first "if" was false
else if (label1.BackColor == Color.Blue)
{
    label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Yes, just add an `else if` there

Answer (score 3):

Why second snippet do not work.

Because in second snippet both `if` statements are independent. After color turns blue from first `if`, the second `if` gets called and changes its color back to Red. You need an `else if`

```
        if (label1.BackColor == Color.Red)
        {
            label1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
        else if (label1.BackColor == Color.Blue)
        {
            label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a logic problem, here is an example of why it doesn't work:

```
// label is blue at this point
if (label1.BackColor == Color.Blue)
{
    // we change the colour to red
}
// label is red at this point
if (label1.BackColor == Color.Red)
{
    // we change it back to blue
}
```

The difference between the statements are the first uses `else` which changes the logic flow so you are only ever dealing with 1 scenario at a time (it's either Red or Blue). However, in the second as they are 2 separate statements you are dealing with both scenarios consecutively. There are a couple of resolutions to this, the most obvious (and probably the best) is to use the `else` like you are already. However, you could also use a `switch`:

```
switch (label1.BackColor)
{
    case Color.Blue:
        label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        break;
    case Color.Red:
        label1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        break;
}
```

You could also keep the code you have in the second snippet but just tell the function you are done by using the `return` keyword e.g.

```
if (label1.BackColor == Color.Blue)
{
    // change to red
    return;
}
```

Or if you want to get really fancy, you could actually refactor the `if` statement out completely and do it in a one liner - looks pretty ugly though...

```
label1.BackColor = checkbox1.Checked ? label1.BackColor = Color.Blue ? Color.Red : Color.Blue : label1.BackColor
```

FYI - `if (checkbox1.Checked == true)` is a pointless check, just use `if (checkbox1.Checked)`

Comment: Depends on if the message that the box is not checked is a requirement.

Comment: @JasonDown the colour should alternate if the checkbox is checked, so in the one-liner if the box isn't checked it just keeps back colour the same. Obviously, if the OP needs to throw a message box up then you wouldn't even need that part as the code would only ever be executed when we are in a "checked" state.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!checkBox1.Checked)
        MessageBox.Show("The box is not checked!");
    else
       label1.BackColor = (label1.BackColor == Color.Red ? Color.Blue : Color.Red);
}
```

Comment: While showing an alternative way can be useful, you are not actually answering the OP's question of why the first case works, but not the second. If you were to answer the question in addition to the alternative way I'd +1 your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting the **2 or more seperate IF statements** then all IF statements are be executed.

If you use **IF ELSE or SWITCH** then any one of that sequence will be executed.

What type of statements should be used you have to decide it.