# if else statement not working

Tags: c#, if-statement, syntax, compiler-errors

The code below is a snippet from a working code that is for a castle maze game in c#.
The if else structure only prints correctly the dun.roomend == true). The tow.roomEnd now displays when the tre.isExit should be displayed. The tre.isExit doesn't display at all.
I have declared the current variables as:

```
public bool isExit;
public bool deadEnd;
public bool roomEnd;

tre.isExit = true;
dun.deadEnd = true;
tow.roomEnd = true;

if (dun.roomEnd == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You've fallen into the Dungeons of the Dead. Try again");
    return;
}

if (tow.roomEnd == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You been caught by the Kings guard and have been placed in the tower for life.Try again");
    return;
}
else if (tre.isExit == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have found the treaure... now run!!");
    return;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Too scared.....");
}
```

Comment: look at your code and step through it using the debugger and pay attention to the bool values just looking at your code it will always hit the first if and return..

Comment: I see your question's been answered but just a tip on your syntax. When assessing bool values in if statements there's no need to use the `==` operator. Instead in your case you can just write `if (dun.roomEnd) {}` and that will do the same as `if (dun.roomEnd == true) {}`. Similarly, to check if it's false use a `!` (known as a not) in front of your bool variable. So essential `if (!dun.roomEnd)` is the same as `if (dun.roomEnd == false)`.

Comment: Thanx for this, its been really helpful. Still struggling with the answer as its not currently working

Comment: Go back to the first comment.  Step thru the code watching each line execute.  You'll learn a lot about how code executes and it will *show you* the logic error.

Comment: Dont change the question once answers are posted - it makes them look wrong and will confuse future readers.  ADD any new information to the original post

Comment: I wanted to add the changed code to get a better understanding of why it was not answering, I cannot do this through comments.

Comment: What @Plutonix is suggesting is that you **additively** edit your question; don't remove content, but edit in something like "**EDIT**: after some discussion I modified the code like this... etc.".  Keeps a running track of how the question evolved, and where the initial answers might've come from.

Comment: `I wanted to add the changed code ...` *That* is ok, but is not what you did.  You *replaced* the original post/question with new/changed code.

Comment: On point with the question, I recommend reading up on [C# Control Structures](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/220356-control-structures-loops-ifs-and-switch/).  Specifically, note that `else` blocks only execute if the `if` blocks before them did not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If / else statements in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251817/if-else-statements-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4):

That's because you immediately return when one of your conditions is true.

```
// Don't explicitly compare to true - just write if (dun.roomEnd)
if (dun.roomEnd == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You've fallen into the Dungeons of the Dead. Try again");
    // You end the method here, so none of the rest of the code after this will execute
    return;
}
```

Also, the fact that you do

```
else if (tre.isExit == true)
```

means that this won't execute if

```
tow.roomEnd == true
```

is also true. "Else if" means "if the current condition is true **and the previous condition is false**", so

```
if (A) {
   // do work
}
else if (B) {
   // Do work
}
```

is semantically equivalent to

```
if (A) {
  // Do work
}

if (!A && B) {
   // Do work
}
```

Finally, I mentioned this in passing, but I'd like to reiterate that it's not necessary to explicitly compare to `true` or `false`, so

```
if (tow.roomEnd == true)
```

should just be

```
if (tow.roomEnd)
```

Also, I don't think it makes sense for all of those conditions to be true at once. Can something *actually* be a room end, a dead end, and an exit at the same time? At a minimum, it seems like a particular location can't be both an exit and a dead end. If the data says that several of those things are true at once, it [needs to be corrected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) in order for the program to function properly.

Comment: removing the two return values before the else if , results  in the same outcome as before with the return values

Comment: make sure you're rebuilding the project after making this change. Or saving the file. What development environment are you using?

Comment: @AmberDyer Because you have `else if (tre.isExit == true)` instead of just `if (tre.isExit == true)`. `else if (tre.isExit == true)` *only* runs when `tow.roomEnd == true` is false, but your example has everything set to true.

Comment: Visual Studio, I have saved it, rebuilt and started it without debugging

Comment: Changing the code with the above suggestions has led to the console outputting both messages for the tre.isExit and tow.roomEnd

Comment: and now has stopped the original if statement working by moving the console message of the tower to the dungeon

Comment: @AmberDyer Incidentally, do you *actually* want all of those conditions to be true at once? Can something actually be a dead end, room end, and exit at the same time?

Comment: well the objects I have created are following a maze structure so they are predetermined and set as that. I'm still really new to c# and slightly confused by this. I want the messages outputted to the screen to be correct that's all.

Comment: @AmberDyer From my perspective that means that the data is wrong then because those are definitely mutually exclusive conditions - a particular location can't possibly be all three of those things by definition.

Comment: oh right :( what is the best approach to correcting the data. A switch statement?

Comment: @AmberDyer How is the data defined? It should be corrected at its source (keeping in mind, of course, that any particular location can only be one of those three things). A switch statement would probably be a good thing here from the logical perspective, but you'd [still need](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) to correct the data.

Answer (score 1):

In every if statement you have keyword `return;`. The return statement terminates execution of the method and because of that only first Console.WriteLine is shown.

Read carefully: [**return (C# Reference)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Reading through what you've done, if I'm understanding this correctly what you're after is as follows.

```
public bool isExit;
public bool deadEnd;
public bool roomEnd;

tre.isExit = true;
dun.deadEnd = true;
tow.roomEnd = true;

if (dun.roomEnd == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You've fallen into the Dungeons of the Dead. Try again");
}
else if (tow.roomEnd)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You been caught by the Kings guard and have been placed in the tower for life.Try again");
}
else if (tre.isExit)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have found the treaure... now run!!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Too scared.....");
}

return
```

This will evaluate each condition individually, and then return once complete.

What this code is effectively saying is "if condition 1 is true, display the text and exit the if block, then return.  Otherwise if condition 2 is true do the same, condition 3 / 4 do the same thing also.

I think this is what you're after at least.  It could be refactored to make it a little simpler but don't have the time to go over that at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for this ,I really appreciate it. Its still showing the wrong messages but I will keep playing with it and hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is showing the Dungeons of the Dead and the Kings Guard message, you need to add an "else" to the if for tow.roomEnd.